# Extracting hashtags from a cell - fixing a 99% working regex formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

I'm trying to use this formula to extract hashtags from a cell. I got it from [this very old topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90296/how-can-social-hashtags-be-extracted-from-a-cell).

`=trim(regexreplace(A2, "((^|\s)[^#]\S*)|([^#\w\s]\S*)", ""))`

Example source:

```
"This is a line before a line break.
#missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag"
```

Current outcome:

```
#2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag
```

Desired outcome:

```
#missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag
```

It mostly works, but I have found a small issue that I'm unable to debug as I'm clueless about REGEX.

It's skipping the first hashtag of a new paragraph. I guess it tries to find words that start with #, but a "break" counts as an invisible character before the #, so what happens is that the first hashtag doesn't get extracted. If I add a space after the break and before the first #, it suddenly works. And also I there's no space before the break, it also works. But would like to fix it to be bulletproof.

I only need to fix that. It would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Actually, I tested some more and if I add a hashtag before the break then something strange happens. The earlier conflictive hashtag works, and the one before the break works too, but they are returned with the break in between, which ideally I'd also like to remove.

Example source:

```
"This is a line before a line break. #thishashtagworks
#missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag"
```

Current outcome:

```
"#thishashtagworks
#missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag"
```

Desired outcome:

```
#thishashtagworks #missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag
```

Comment: The formula doesn't return to me the reported result, it returns

`#missinghashtag #2ndhashtag #3rdhashtag` 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5fLo.png I copy / pasted the sample text and the formula, just changing A2 to A1 to save space. Maybe the original source is some sort of hidden characters (html entities, unicode, ...?). Please add more details about what is the source of the sample text, i.e. if you typed directly into the edit box or if you copied and pasted, if you copied and pasted, please use the web browser inspector tool to check the source code of the original text.

Comment: I also guess it's some sort of invisible character, I thought it was a break, but doesn't seem to be.
The text came from Airtable, and some other user typed it, so can't be sure. 
https://prnt.sc/cxUx3tUzAwrQ

In the HTML no character appears, not even the break tbh. Bout you can see the break in the field, and when I copy pasted it in the example spreadsheet I shared. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sF8abQyUsR4vVRgBM0wv1vbbZPfTYq5Ei-kie2u5ISk/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=trim(regexreplace(A2, "(\r+)|(\n+)|((^|\s)[^#]\S*)|([^#\w\s]\S*)", " "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Your solution works to solve the 2nd issue, and removes the line break delivering the result in a single line. But when removing the hashtag before the line break, the hashtag right after still doesn't get extracted. :(

Comment: @Chaoscontrol - Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @RohitGupta I did (upvote it). :) I did not accept is as a complete solution as it didn't solve my main problem.

Comment: @Chaoscontrol please post a link to a file that shows your problem

Comment: Sure, sorry. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sF8abQyUsR4vVRgBM0wv1vbbZPfTYq5Ei-kie2u5ISk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Double checking now, I can see the problem wasn't the break, but the space before the break itself. Is there a way to fix that? It's pretty common for people to add a space after a period, so can't rely on people NOT doing it all the time.

Comment: ok, now go and see your modified file :) the final formula being: `=trim(regexreplace(A1, "(\s\r+)|(\s\n+)|(\n+)|((^|\s)[^#]\S*)|([^#\w\s]\S*)", " "))`

Comment: Epic, now it's perfect. Thank you SO much @Daniele

Comment: Hi @Daniele, sorry but I'm still having some trouble with this.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qUkpTIHqCGUosH1tte83X9GQuyMZngzmagcySfOKSZg/edit?usp=sharing

It's still missing a hashtag when there's a double space as well. Tried some tweak with my nonexistent regex experience, but didn't manage. :(

Edit: oh I think I've got it. I added another conditional with (\s\s+). Not sure if I should keep the +, it makes no difference to the result.